# Websockets request getting 404 on my website - repeated tries on mediawiki pages

Tags: websocket, http-status-code-404, mediawiki

This started yesterday morning about 4pm GMT.  So far three individual IP addresses.  I have anonymized the ip addresses with NNN.

In all three cases, they searched and successfully hit one of my media wiki pages.  Two of them got a pattern of 408 errors.  Then they started repeat spamming of "websocket" requests - and as far as I know websocket is not implemented on my site.  One also reflects Ajax Error CB.  One shows "Plugin:ABN".

It would appear that some browser or browser add-in is misbehaving.  In one case the initial search was Bing so it could be Windows 10.  What is annoying is spamming 2000 websocket requests that get an error 404 on my website over a 6 hour period.

Any ideas on what would cause this?  In the last 24 hours these three sites generating about 5000 error 404's on my website:

Apache log:`Case 1 from 76.30.86.NNN - Comcast IP Address in US.

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:10:20:22 -0700] "GET /support/kb/Repair/Re-install_Outlook_2003,_2007,_2010,_2013,_2016 HTTP/1.1" 200 10411 "https://www.bing.com/search?q=install+microsoft+outlook&FORM=QSRE4" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:25:24 -0700] "-" 408 137 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:30:25 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:35:25 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:40:25 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:45:26 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:50:26 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:10:55:26 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:11:00:27 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:11:05:27 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:11:10:27 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

76.30.86.NNN - - [18/Sep/2019:11:15:28 -0700] "-" 408 3284 "-" "-"

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:11:15:28 -0700] "GET /82A2C3C3-09A7-A741-99A9-2EC607BE97FF/init?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fsupport%2Fkb%2FRepair%2FRe-install_Outlook_2003%2C_2007%2C_2010%2C_2013%2C_2016&isTopLevel=true&nocache=14f0e HTTP/1.1" 301 4417 "https://www.mywebsite.com/support/kb/Repair/Re-install_Outlook_2003,_2007,_2010,_2013,_2016" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:11:15:28 -0700] "GET /82A2C3C3-09A7-A741-99A9-2EC607BE97FF/websocket?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fsupport%2Fkb%2FRepair%2FRe-install_Outlook_2003%2C_2007%2C_2010%2C_2013%2C_2016&nocache=1568830527710 HTTP/1.1" 301 4336 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

**snip - repeats approx every second for 2040 times**

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:17:15:57 -0700] "GET /82A2C3C3-09A7-A741-99A9-2EC607BE97FF/init/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fsupport%2Fkb%2FRepair%2FRe-install_Outlook_2003%2C_2007%2C_2010%2C_2013%2C_2016&isTopLevel=true&nocache=10fec HTTP/1.1" 404 55891 "https://www.mywebsite.com/support/kb/Repair/Re-install_Outlook_2003,_2007,_2010,_2013,_2016" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:17:15:57 -0700] "GET /82A2C3C3-09A7-A741-99A9-2EC607BE97FF/init?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fsupport%2Fkb%2FRepair%2FRe-install_Outlook_2003%2C_2007%2C_2010%2C_2013%2C_2016&isTopLevel=true&nocache=10fec HTTP/1.1" 301 4417 "https://www.mywebsite.com/support/kb/Repair/Re-install_Outlook_2003,_2007,_2010,_2013,_2016" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:18:48:27 -0700] "GET /support/kb/Repair/Re-install_Outlook_2003,_2007,_2010,_2013,_2016 HTTP/1.1" 200 10412 "https://www.bing.com/search?q=install+microsoft+outlook&FORM=QSRE4" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

c-76-30-86-NNN.hsd1.tx.comcast.net - - [18/Sep/2019:19:44:52 -0700] "GET /support/kb/Repair/Re-install_Outlook_2003,_2007,_2010,_2013,_2016 HTTP/1.1" 200 10413 "https://www.bing.com/search?q=install+microsoft+outlook&FORM=QSRE4" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

`